# U(n)mount sthealthily without notifying applications or clearing cache. (testing purposes)

Tags: mount, partition, devices, unmounting

There is already:

```
 $ umount -l
```

.

But is there a way to unmount silently?

This means, in example: If a photo on the unmounted partition is inside of a device, then Linux should preferrably keep it in the cache, the file managers should still display the files and folders, and the cached files should be accessible until that cache space is needed for something else.

#### How can a partition be unmounted sthealthily?

Comment: Errr, no, pretty sure there isn't, as the cache is dependent on the filesystem. This seems like a very odd requirement; what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you have found no approach in `man umount`.

So long as devices are accessed through device-mapper (`/dev/mapper/` / `/dev/dm-*`), you can implement surprising re-mappings with `dmsetup`. Conveniently this includes

```
   remove [-f|--force] device_name
          Removes a device.  It will no  longer  be  visible  to  dmsetup.
          Open  devices  cannot  be removed except with older kernels that
          contain a version of device-mapper prior to 4.8.0.  In this case
          the  device  will  be deleted when its open_count drops to zero.
          From version 4.8.0 onwards, if a device can't be removed because
          an uninterruptible process is waiting for I/O to return from it,
          adding --force will replace the table with one  that  fails  all
          I/O, which might allow the process to be killed.
```

I thought you might get more reliable behaviour if you could do the equivalent at the filesystem level, but the options for this seem to be even more obscure. E.g. you want some construction like a FUSE network filesystem, sshfs...  as a network filesystem it must support read caching... and from the man page it looks like the cache timeouts e.g. for dirs can be set high as you would need... sshfs supports retries, so you should be able to kill the SSH listener...  In this example, reads not satisfied by cache would hard-block indefinitely.

Hence I suggest spending some time with the device mapper and `dmsetup`.

In either case, you're not unmounting the filesystem used by the application.  The mount entry will still be visible in `/proc/mounts` etc.  This will be absolutely necessary; an open file must point to some filesystem. Instead, you're detaching that filesystem from its original backing store.

Comment: Thank you. I already knew `umount -f`, but I had not tested it yet.